# MIT App inventor How to save a game in-mid progress

Tags: app-inventor

Is there a way to set up a system of block codes to save a game in-mid progress. I designed a game with multi-screens that requires the player to move through scenarios that their choices affect the game's ending.

If a player wants to stop in the middle of a scenario and save the game to come back to it later, how would the coding look like?

Comment: save everything what needs to be saved in TinyDB and read again TinyDB while initializing the app

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tiny db component to store all the variables with tags and when the game loads ask the user if they want to resume. if they say yes, load the variables back in and render position, etc.

You can find the details of tinyDb component [here.](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/storage.html)